# How to run MSBuild file after TFS done building successfully?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

So, i recently set up an TFS build server, server could build and test, not problems there, however i found out that MsBuild cant publish to ftp directly. so i search on the internet, of what exactly i can do to solve my problem.
I found [ms build tasks extension](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) which have possibility to publish files to ftp.  The problem i am facing right now is that i cant really figure out how to use it. I am using default build process template, with few changes. I dont understand if i have to change that template, or i have to write a brand new template? Or do i have to change in VS project file? or how do i get started? I never worked with MSBuild before. So the question is, how do i get started?

There are plenty information on the internet, but i couldnt find a plain dummy explanation of how to integrate this library and make it work together with TFS.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better to love your ftp your to PowerShell.

If you use the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml you should see a post test script location. Here you can specify a PowerShell to fun after your build has finished and tests have passed. This would be much easeyer to support long term.

Comment: If i do that i am getting wrong directory error. I have tried to create separapte ps1 script which uploads files from newly created build, but cant get pass this error

Comment: Then your powershell is referencing the wrong location. There is a plethora of good docs out there on how to move files around in powershell from TFS Build.